# java class, extending external API functionality

Tags: java, methods, extends

I have an external API (I can't modify it) with class "A" and local class "B" which overrides methods of "A" and adds an additional function.
I need to use one of them according to some parameter "is_A".

/*------ API (A.java) -----*/

```
package A;

public class A {

    public int pingA( int value ) {

        return value;

    }

}
```

/*------ my class (B.java) -----*/

```
package B;

import A.*;

public class B extends A {

    @Override
    public int pingA( int value ) {
        return value;
    }

    public int pingB( int value ) {
        return value;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final boolean is_A = false;
        A obj;
        if (is_A) {
            obj = new A();
        } else {
            obj = new B();
        }
        if (!is_A) {
            int n = obj.pingB(3);
        }
    }
}
```

In this case I want to use class "B", but the command "int n = obj.pingB(3);" is not compiled because there is no method pingB in A. 
The exact message is:

```
cannot find symbol
symbol: method pingB(int)
location: class A.A
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [cast](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) `obj` back to `B`.

```
if (!is_A) {
    int n = ((B) obj).pingB(3);
}
```

You can by the way better use the [`instanceof`](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html) keyword instead of `is_A`.

```
if (obj instanceof B) {
    int n = ((B) obj).pingB(3);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works.
Should this approach (I mean casting) affect the processing speed?

Answer (score 7):

You're adding a new method in a subclass which does not exist in the super class. There is no way to call the new method in the subclass using a reference to the superclass. You'd have to cast to to the subclass type to use the new method.

You could do something like:

```
A obj = new B();

if (obj instance of B) {
   B b = (B)obj;
   int n = b.pingB(3);
}
```

Here `B` is a `A` but `A` is not a `B` so it doesn't have the pingB(int) method.

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast to your derived class to be able to call it's methods. Usually that is done with and `if( obj instanceof B )` but as you already have a boolean with that information it's going to look like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 
    final boolean is_A = false; 
    A obj; 
    if (is_A) { 
        obj = new A(); 
    } else { 
        obj = new B(); 
    } 
    if (!is_A) { 
        int n = ((B) obj).pingB(3); 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

obj is still having the type A (-> you declared A obj;) -> this way the type binding does not work for compilation.